# Get id in array from array object in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-multiselect

I'm new in Vue js, and I have data in array object like below when I use vue-multiselect.

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "add_on_type": "Xtra",
            "name": "test",
            "price": 12,
            "created_at": "2020-06-25 10:12:43",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-25 10:12:43"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "add_on_type": "Xtra",
            "name": "Some x",
            "price": 120,
            "created_at": "2020-06-30 05:47:52",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-30 05:47:52"
        }
    ]
```

but in my function I need to access like `key:value` like below

```
"xtra": {
  // key: value
  0: 1
  1: 3
}
```

but I get all array object instead of `id` only. I need to get the `ID` only in array, below is my code. I don't know how to get only `id` from `array` using below code.

```
this.$axios
      .get("items/" + this.item)
      .then(res => {
        // below line is how I get the array object, but I need only id in array.
        data.xtra = this.extra;
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
```

this maybe easy for some people, but I cannot find the way to to do. any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: `yourSourceArray.map(({id}) => id)`

Comment: wow it's correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, `this.item` is holding an object retrieved from the array. If is like this, it should be as easy as:

```
  .get("items/" + this.item.id)
```

Comment: my question is after `res` only.. the `get` is not necessary.. `data.xtra = this.extra;`

Comment: yeah solved it like `yourSourceArray.map(({id}) => id)`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create new array you can do this at your return from axios

```
.then(res => {
  let arr = res.data
  this.xtra = arr.map(x =>
  x.item.id)

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare Items as reactive array in setup function

```
 const tools = reactive([]);
```

Then in methods, retrieve

```
axios.get("/user-items").then(response => {
                            
       var items = [];
       response.data.forEach((item, index) => {
           items.push(item.id);
       })
       Object.assign(this.items, items);
                        
});
```